# Benchmark gives command execution timed out

Tags: go, aerospike

Im trying to do a small performance/implementation comparison between redis and aerospike using go, but my aerospike code get a "command execution timed out." error after a while.

I installed aerospike server according to the site, and the supplied benchmark with the go client works without error so maybe Im doing something wrong in my code?

I run the test with

```
-bench="1AerospikeCounter" -benchtime 30s -cpu=1 -parallel=1
```

If I enable logging this is the output, the panic happens at the error check after PutObject.

```
2015/05/14 10:20:55 Connection to address `127.0.0.1:3000` failed to establish with error: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3000: cannot assign requested address
2015/05/14 10:20:55 Node BB9DC1A8E565000 127.0.0.1:3000: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3000: cannot assign requested address
panic: command execution timed out.

goroutine 20 [running]:
backend/gateway/core/database.UpdateWithDelta(0xc218aeea20, 0x60c7c, 0x3fde23dba43075e1, 0xc221f181d0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /root/go/src/backend/gateway/core/database/database_test.go:247 +0x294
```

My code looks like

```
type Counter struct {
    Id  int
    Pop float64
}

func Benchmark2AerospikeCounter(b *testing.B) {
    logger.Logger.SetLevel(logger.INFO)
    clientPolicy := aerospike.NewClientPolicy()
    asclient, err := aerospike.NewClientWithPolicy(clientPolicy, "127.0.0.1", 3000)
    if err != nil {
        b.Fatal(err)
    }
    b.ResetTimer()

    b.RunParallel(func(pb *testing.PB) {
        for pb.Next() {
            x := rand.Intn(1000000)
            y := rand.Float64()
            delta := Counter{Id: x, Pop: y}
            _, err := UpdateWithDelta(asclient, delta)
            if err != nil {
                b.Fatal(err)
            }
        }
    })
}

func UpdateWithDelta(client *aerospike.Client, delta Counter) (*Counter, error) {
    key, err := aerospike.NewKey("test", "counters", delta.Id)
    oldCounter := &Counter{}
    err = client.GetObject(client.DefaultPolicy, key, oldCounter)
    if v, ok := err.(types.AerospikeError); ok {
        if v.ResultCode() != types.KEY_NOT_FOUND_ERROR {
            return nil, err
        }
    } else if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    newCounter := &Counter{
        Id:  delta.Id,
        Pop: oldCounter.Pop + delta.Pop,
    }

    err = client.PutObject(client.DefaultWritePolicy, key, newCounter)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return newCounter, err
}
```

I run it on a virtualized CentOS box, I followed the basic aerospike installation instructions and then just started it. Note that I get the same error if I put the db on a separate machine.

ps. If someone from aerospike is reading: It doesnt seems to be possible to signup with google on your forum.

Comment: You're timeout is in `Benchmark1AerospikeCounter`, but you're showing us code for `Benchmark2AerospikeCounter`. The timeout occurred at `database_test.go:195`; what line is that?

Comment: You also have an error that says `dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3000: cannot assign requested address`. What resources are allotted to your test program? Are you exhausting open FDs or ports?

Comment: @JimB Right, sorry about the error. My real code is more advanced and had to cut it down a bit to post here and pasted the wrong error. Ive updated my question.

Comment: @JimB I have not done any tweaking regarding resources. If I check the aerospike.log I cant find any CRITICAL errors like mentioned on the aerospike FAQ page as an indication of FD shortage.

Comment: I'm not saying you've changed any resources, I'm just saying you're exhausting some. The "cannot assign requested address" error means the OS won't or can't give you a socket for a new connection. Depending on how the aerospike client works, you may need to limit the number of connections it's allowed, or you need to increase the limits for your process.

Comment: I notice that I get a lot of tcp connections when it start to happen, so tried setting LimitConnectionsToQueueSize to true. That lowered the tcp connections from 10k+ to >1k when the timeout happens, but I still get command execution timed out.

Comment: Alerted internally about the googleid not working on the forums

Comment: The google id login is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a subtle bug on the Go client that would not let the connections go back to the connection pool on non-critical errors like KEY_NOT_FOUND_ERROR.

Your code works now.

ps. I'm not on stackoverflow, sorry for the late reply.